# Display previous post instead of the latest post

Tags: mysql, wordpress-theming

On wordpress I have a littl box that displays the latest post from a category.
The code looks like this:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'category_name' => 'updates'
```

If I wanted to create a second box that displays not the latest post but the one before how should I approach it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `get_posts()` function like this:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(    
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'category_name' => 'updates'
));
```

and you can access the second post with `$posts[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Eventually I got what I wanted with the following:

```
<?php $args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'order' => 'DESC',
'order_by' => 'date',
'category_name' => 'updates',
'limit' => '1',
'offset' => '1'
```

For the following boxes it becomes:

```
'offset' => '2' and 'offset' => '3'
```